# Save selected radio button values even after closing the app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Im trying to make a feature for my app where the user can fill a questionnaire with radio buttons and he can save the progress and can return later to finish it.
Take a look at this code:

```
const Step3 = () => {
  const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([]);
  const [answers, setAnswers] = useState([]);
  const {addQuest} = useContext(AuthContext);
  const getQuestions = async () => {
    const locale = 'sq'; // TODO: get current locale
    const response = await apiStandarts.get(`/questions?locale=${locale}`, {
      params: { _limit: MAX_QUESTIONS, active: 1, _sort:'sortId:ASC' },
    });
    setQuestions(response.data);
  };
    const isOptionSelected = (option) => {
      const answer = answers[option.question]
        if (answer) {
          return option.id == answer.id
        }
      return false;
    }
    const saveData = () =>{
    AsyncStorage.setItem('questions', JSON.stringify(answers)).then(() => {
      console.log('data saved', answers)
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })}
    const retrieveData = async () => {
      try {
        const answers = await AsyncStorage.getItem('questions');
        const parsed = JSON.parse(answers);
        Alert.alert(`${parsed.id}`);
      } catch(error) {
        Alert.alert(error)
      }
    }
    

  useEffect(() => {
    getQuestions();
  }, []);
  
  const OptionList = (groupOption) => {
    
    return (
      <FlatList
        data={groupOption.options}
        keyExtractor={(result) => result.id.toString()}
        renderItem={({ item, index}) => {
          const clickedRadio = () => {
            const selectedOption = {[item.question]:{...item}}
            setAnswers({...answers, ...selectedOption})
            console.log(answers)
          }
          const status = isOptionSelected(item) ? true : false
          return (
            <View key={index}>
              <Radio initialValue={status} label={item.description} onChange={() => clickedRadio()}/>
            </View>
          );
        }}
      />
    );
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={{ fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: 16, color: "#6B24AA" }}>
        {t("Choose an option/Scroll for more questions")}
      </Text>
      <FlatList
        data={questions}
        keyExtractor={(result) => result.id.toString()}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
          return (
            <View style={styles.groupOptions} key={index}>
              <Text>{item.description}</Text>
              <OptionList options={item?.question_options}></OptionList>
            </View>
          );
        }}
      />
      <Button onPress={() => addQuest({answers})}>Save progress</Button>
      <Button onPress={() => retrieveData()}>Get progress</Button>
    </View>

  )
}
```

I've tried with AsyncStorage but i get my questions from an API and the data re-renders every time the app opens again. Any ideas how to achieve this ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Tracking user progress should be done on the back-end if possible; in case the user has created an account.  Saving in Async Storage will require a lot of effort.

I do freelance consulting, I can rent a help hand .

Comment: @BYIRINGIROEmmanuel just did something like that, i post the answers in database, but after that im stuck on how to call it back and the values to stay selected. Thank you tho you've been very helpful

Comment: Ideally, it's recommended to fetch previous answers when for questionnaire when available  and keep a check if the user answered that question, if yes , UI will  render based on previously provide answers

Comment: how bout question ? is it dynamic ? if not then store both at local. when finish they push to backend

Comment: @BYIRINGIROEmmanuel yeah thats what im gonna figure out how to do thanks.

Comment: @Edofx the questions are the same for everybody, so i would say it can be done that way to